# Sub in VBA that Takes a Range

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a `Sub` in VBA that takes a `Range`:

```
Sub MarkCell(ByRef rng As Range, value As String)
    For Each C In Range.Cells
        If C = value Then
            aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next C
End Sub
```

But I'm getting a "Compile Error: Argument not optional" on my `For` statement. What am I missing?

Comment: `For Each C In Range.Cells` should be `For Each C In rng.Cells` or the equivalent `For Each C In rng`. Also note that your code will fail unless aCell is declared and assigned to outside of the sub. I think you mean `C.Interior.ColorIndex = 3` (but perhaps not ;))

Comment: It's always a bad idea to use reserved words as the names of variables. Change `value` to something like `sValue` or `sVALU`. I'd also recommend specifying that you want to compare `C.Value` to the string parameter passed in and you might want to remove case sensitivity with `If UCase(C.Value) = UCase(sVALU) Then`. The declaration of `C` as a range object and using `rng` in the `For ... Next` loop has already been pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to refer to the `rng` parameter. Not the `Range` class.

So fix your code as shown below.

```
For Each C In rng.Cells
    If C = value Then
        C.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next C
```